# Why is my Scan.nextDouble giving me an error for java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a really new programmer and I've been practicing to get better. I hate to ask for help with what I'm sure is a juvenile question for a class, but I cant figure it out.The error it gives is this:  It gives me this error : Lab7d.java:28: error: cannot find symbol newArray[i] = scan.nextDouble(). Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lab7d {
   public static void main (String[] args){

      // Lab7d, [Naqeeb Nazir], [Masc 1555]

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numInputs = scan.nextInt();


      double[] quakes = new double[numInputs];
      quakes = init(numInputs, scan.nextDouble());


      getMagnitudeStats(quakes);


      print(quakes);

      }


      public static double[] init(int a, double n) {
       double[] newArray = new double[a];
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        newArray[i] = scan.nextDouble();
          }
          return newArray;
      }


       public static void getMagnitudeStats(double[] myArray) {
         double Maximum = 0.0;
         double Minimum = 0.0;
         double Average = 0.0;
         int severeEarthquakes = 0;

         if (Minimum > 0 && Minimum <= 10.0) Minimum = myArray[0];
         else Minimum = 1.0;

         if (Maximum > 0 && Maximum <= 10.0) Maximum = myArray[0];
         else Maximum = 1.0;




         System.out.println("Maximum: " + Maximum);
         System.out.println("Minimum: " + Minimum);
         System.out.println("Average: " + Average);
         System.out.println("Severe earthquakes: " + severeEarthquakes);


         }



      public static void print(double[] myArray1) {
         for (int i = 0; i < myArray1.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(myArray1[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
         }

   }
```

Comment: You forgot to tell what error it is

Comment: The program we use, Zybooks, enters four different inputs. The first one is 5.1 2.6 6.5 9.2 6.1 5.6 5.5  4.9 3.88 5.448 1.65 9.45  6.21 7.88 5.94. 
The output is supposed to be Maximum: 9.5
Minimum: 1.7
Average: 5.7
Severe earthquakes: 3
5.1 2.6 6.5 9.2 6.1 5.6 5.5 4.9 3.88 5.448 1.65 9.45 6.21 7.88 5.94.

The closest I can get as of now is
Maximum: 1.0
Minimum: 1.0
Average: 0.0
Severe earthquakes: 0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `scan` variable is defined in `main()`, but you are trying to access it in `init()`. That is why you get `error: cannot find symbol`.

You can make `scan` an instance variable and declare it outside the `main()` method.

Or do the following to create `scan` in `init()`:

```
public static double[] init(int a, double n) {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   double[] newArray = new double[a];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    newArray[i] = scan.nextDouble();
      }
      return newArray;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I tried to do this however and received this error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
 at Lab7d.init(Lab7d.java:29)
 at Lab7d.main(Lab7d.java:14).

Comment: @BorntoCode what are your lines 29 and 14 in Lab7d.java?

Comment: Its better you try to make `scan` an instance variable. Before your `main()` method do `static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);` and use this `scan` in all your methods.

Answer (score 2):

`scan` is a local variable in `main`, you can't access it in `init()` here   `newArray[i] = scan.nextDouble();`